# "find . -type d | wc -l" showing 1 more directory than actual count

Tags: bash

Can anybody tell me why the command

```
find . -type d | wc -l
```

shows one directory more than the actual number of directories? The command is supposed to print number of directories and subdirectories, from the directory I am standing. The command

```
ls -lR | grep ^d | wc -l
```

does the same thing, but in this case I get the correct number. Same case when I use `f` or - (file) instead. It just adds one more directory/file.

Comment: `mkdir foo; cd foo; mkdir 1 2 3; find . -type d`

Comment: Because `find` also finds `.`.

Comment: is there any way to exclude this?

Comment: Also, `mkdir $'foo\nbar\nbaz'` will create one directory that counts as 3 if the name is printed literally (some `find` implementations will escape it, some won't). Relying on the default `-print` action is bad form.

Comment: BTW, re: `ls -lR | grep`, see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww, how does this one read to you as a question more coupled to interactive use than script development? (I frequently close such questions as off-topic myself, but this one doesn't strike me that way).

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible sources of error:

- The current directory itself
- Directories with literal newlines in their names

---

#### GNU find (with `-printf`)

To eliminate both, when using GNU find:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

- Putting `-mindepth 1` prevents the named argument (`.`) from matching.
- Using `-printf '\n'` instead of the default `-print` action ensures that the name itself can't change how a file is counted.

---

#### GNU *or* BSD find (with `-print0`)

With modern BSD `find` (as on MacOS), you may not have `-printf` but still will have `-print0`. Thus, for code compatible with both major implementations:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c
```

`tr -cd '\0'` removes all characters other than NULs; `wc -c` counts characters remaining in the stream -- thus, counting the remaining NUL delimiters, thus counting files. (A NUL is the only character safe for this use, as it isn't permitted to exist in a path).

---

#### POSIX find (with `-exec`)

If you don't have `-printf` or `-print0`, you can still delegate the job of printing something safe (like the number of arguments) to a shell:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "$#"' _ {} + | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

Answer (score 1):

It counts the current directory as well.  If you want to eliminate that you can set the mindepth variable to 1.

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

will only give the count of child directories...

Answer (score -1):

Don't print the dirname, but a dot. If you don't collect dirs with linebreaks, like most of us, piping to wc -l is of course the easy solution - you just need to know when to abstain from it.

```
concat=$(find . -mindepth 1 -type d -printf ".")
echo ${#concat}
66
```

Comment: One need not be intentionally collecting things to have them around. I'm sure you've already heard my war story about a random buffer-o-garbage getting dumped into a filename leading to a major dataloss event. (Not criticizing the answer, just responding to the commentary). And when I'm in pentester mode, I might create such cases intentionally.

Comment: In over 99% of the cases, when I use find, I know roughly what to expect. I have one directory which contains toxic filenames, made by myself for experimenting for just such cases. In /etc, /lib, /usr and /var I find no difference between a secure and a lazy approach, so there seems to be a good reason to avoid linebreaks in dir/filenames which leads to them being quiet rare. They are antiergonomic for lazy coders and admins, I guess, is the reason. But blanks in filenames are slowly getting ground - most often in filenames as company product names.

Comment: If you have line breaks in your filenames or directory names, perhaps you're in the wrong profession! :)

Comment: @karakfa: Your employer might be, your customers, coworkers and so on. Some tools generate filenames automatically, based on incomplete assumptions. Filenames, generated from media come to mind...

Comment: @karakfa, ...if a 3rd-party library a coworker used has a buffer overflow (which is how it happened in the occasion I frequently retell), you're in the wrong profession? And note that "pentester" is a profession; so is "black-hat", and either or both may end up in your networks (or doing a man-in-the-middle on unencrypted traffic to/from your systems) trying to find exploitable corner cases in systems they haven't yet gotten a foothold in.

Comment: That said, I agree that it's not the usual 99% of cases that one needs to be worrying about; problem is that the problematic <1% isn't guaranteed to show up only when you expect them to. :)

Answer (score -1):

`find` also finds the current directory `.`. You may also have other directories beginning with `.`, e.g. `.config`.

To recursively count all directories, including those beginning with `.`:

```
find * .* -type d | wc -l
```

To recursively count all directories, but exclude those beginning with `.`:

```
find * -type d | wc -l
```